# common class error displayed after composer package install

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, composer-php

I installed xampp-windows-x64-8.1.10-0-VS16-installer

and wanted to add some packages. my compsoser.json looks like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "bensquire/php-image-optim": "dev-master",
    "jlevers/selling-partner-api": "^5.4"

},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "phpstan/extension-installer": true
    }
}
```

}

composer update i got the following error when I want to open phpmyadmin:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpMyAdmin\Common" not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php:40 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 40

I googled the error, but didnt find an answer.  what could it be?

Comment: phpmyadmin is not configured properly and can't load all of its classes it needs to run, for the specific message you summon, it is at least the class **PhpMyAdmin\Common** . Consult the operations manual of that application and double check it has been properly set-up for the system you have under test. If it is from a ready-made solution, you can also try reinstalling and/or look for support resources at the vendors site. The composer.json in question looks disconnected to the problem to me as it does not have phpmyadmin as a dependency. Please [edit], elaborate  and add all the infos.

Comment: How is opening phpMyAdmin related to the given composer.json?